# Get-Process doesnt work on buttonpress in a .net form

Tags: powershell, user-interface, process

I have the following code where i test a few misc. things:

```
Function Get-FileName
{
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  [String]$Dateien = "*"
)   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $EingabeFenster = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $EingabeFenster.initialDirectory = "C:"
 $EingabeFenster.filter = “All files (*.$Dateien)| *.$Dateien”
 $EingabeFenster.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $EingabeFenster.filename
}

Function Set-WallPaper($pfad)
{
 Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $pfad
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}

Function Get-Wallpaperpath
{
$Bildpfad = Get-FileName($Dateien = "bmp")
Set-WallPaper -value "$Bildpfad"
}

Function Get-Prompthash
{
$Hashpfad = Get-FileName($Dateien = "*")
$Test = Get-FileHash -Path "$Hashpfad"
Write-Host $Test.hash
}

Function Get-Processname
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$Procname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Gebe Prozessnamen ein", "Prozessabfrage")
Get-Process $Procname
}

function GenerateForm { 
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(“System.Windows.Forms”) | Out-Null 
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(“System.Drawing”) | Out-Null 
$MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState 

$handler_Button1_Click= 
{ 
Get-Wallpaperpath
}

$handler_Button2_Click=
{
Get-Prompthash
}

$handler_Button3_Click=
{
Get-Processname
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection= 
{
$MainForm.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState 
}
$MainForm.Text = “Fenster” 
$MainForm.Name = “MainForm” 
$MainForm.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 165 
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 125 
$MainForm.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$Button1.TabIndex = 0 
$Button1.Name = “Button1” 
$Button2.TabIndex = 1
$Button2.Name = "Button2"
$Button2.TabIndex = 2
$Button2.Name = "Button3"

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 130 
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 22 
$Button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Button1.Text = “Hintergrund setzen”

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140 
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 22 
$Button2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Button2.Text = “Hashwert berechnen”

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140 
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 22 
$Button3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Button3.Text = “Test3”

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13 
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13 
$Button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point 
$Button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Button1.add_Click($handler_Button1_Click)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13 
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 53 
$Button2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point 
$Button2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Button2.add_Click($handler_Button2_Click)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13 
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 93 
$Button3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point 
$Button3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Button3.add_Click($handler_Button3_Click)

$MainForm.Controls.Add($Button1) 
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Button2) 
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Button3) 
$InitialFormWindowState = $MainForm.WindowState
$MainForm.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
$MainForm.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
}

GenerateForm
```

The problem is the `Get-Process` - it does not seem to work: The `$Procname` stores the value and passes it to the function, but it does not return anything at all. I tested it, and when i run only the `Get-Processname` function, it worked as expected. Only when i include the function into my GUI and have it run on buttonpress it does not work. I dont understand how this problem is caused.

Comment: You need to assign the output from `Get-Processname` to _something_ - if you just leave it as-is inside the `Click` event action block it'll simply vanish into the ether :)

Comment: So what should i change? Something like replace the `$handler_Button3_Click=` part with `Write-Host Get-Processname` or what?

Comment: Something like that (`$procname = Get-Processname;Write-Host $procname`), yes :)

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the problem - if i do it like this, it just prints out `System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.D
iagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnosti
cs.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Proce
ss (chrome) System.Diagnostics.Process (chrome)`

Comment: Well, it clearly does, but _what are you trying to achieve_? Where and in what format (and for what purpose) do you want the output from `Get-Processname`?

Comment: I want to output the standard Get-Process output to the shell - the standard output should be something like this: (probably poorly formated in SO comments)
`PS C:\windows\system32> get-process Chrome

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                                  
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    218      52    70776      97436   459    17,64   1228 chrome
    710     459    25668      42640   230    86,59   1564 chrome` (Just check yourself so you understand)